# Unable to autorefresh my chart using javascript

Tags: javascript, charts

Chart is loading fine but I'm unable to autorefresh this chart, tried setInterval(drawChart, 10000); and is not working.  Did I place the interval in the wrong position?  function is drawChart.

```
   function drawChart(candlestickChartDataOptions, candlestickChartData, chart_id) {
   var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(candlestickChartData, true);
   var options = {

   chartArea: {
   left: 40,
   top: 20,
   width: "100%",
   height: "70%"
              },

    legend:"none",
    title:candlestickChartDataOptions.currency1+" price in "+candlestickChartDataOptions.currency2,
    bar: { groupWidth: "70%" ,


         }, // sets space between bars
    candlestick: {
    fallingColor: { strokeWidth: 0, fill: "#a52714" }, // red
    risingColor: { strokeWidth: 0, fill: "#0f9d58" },  // green

          }
          };
    var chart = new google.visualization.CandlestickChart(document.getElementById(chart_id));

    chart.draw(data, options);
        }

   jQuery( document ).ready(function() {

   jQuery( "select#chart_period_'.$chart_id.'" ).change(function() {
   setCandlestickPeriod(candlestickChartDataOptions_'.$chart_id.', jQuery(this).val());
   candlestickLoadData(candlestickChartDataOptions_'.$chart_id.', "'.$chart_id.'");

   });

   drawChart();

   setInterval(drawChart, 10000);     


   });

   </script>

   <div id="<?php echo $chart_id; ?>"></div>
```

Also tried this and is not working too, the $chart_id is correct:

```
    <script>

   setInterval(function(){

   $("<?php echo $chart_id; ?>").load(document.URL + " <?php echo 
   $chart_id; ?>");

   }, 10000)   


    </script>
```

What went wrong? Please help thanks.

Comment: Use `setTimeOut` instead of `setInterval`, if you want to  make it reload once. `setInterval` would  reload it after every 1 sec. Do tell me if it worked or no!

Comment: @Karan Dhir hi, I need it to reload every sec or few seconds